# How to import a GitHub hosted project as a Java Project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, github

I have forked this project on my GitHub:

- https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns

and now I'm trying to import (clone) my own *origin* repo locally. I managed to do it via Bash command line, but I'm not being able to import the project in Eclipse and make it a "Java Project". It's imported as a "Generic project" where packages are seen as plain directories:

[image]

The import wizard gives these 3 options:

[image]

If I go with the first one it says "No projects found" and if I go with the second I have no idea how to proceed.

Is this the wrong way to go? I'm using Eclipse Mars (4.5.1) with EGit plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to import is actually a Maven project. First of all, make sure you have [M2Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) installed, so that the projects can be imported and built automatically.

What I usually do in those cases is the following (pictures are taken with Eclipse Mars 4.5.1, you will need to adjust with your Eclipse installation but it shouldn't change much):

- Clone the Git repository with the URL: `https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns.git`.

  [image]
- Select the `master` branch only

  [image]
- Once Eclipse has downloaded everything, I *do not* use the import facility but instead let Eclipse finish and do nothing.

  [image]

At this point, there are 2 approaches possible. The repository is checked out into your machine, and the projects need to be imported in Eclipse as Maven projects.

#### Solution 1: Import as Maven project from the Git perspective

**NOTE:** this solution requires the `m2e-egit` connector to be installed. [Refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36824717/1743880) to locate and install it. The connector will be located at the bottom of the list, below the "m2e Team providers" section, and is named `m2e-egit`.

- Still in the Git perspective, expand the Git repository, right-click "Working Tree", and select "Import Maven Projects..."

  [image]

#### Solution 2: Import as Maven project from the Import facility

- Go to "File > Import... > Existing Maven Projects".

  [image]

In both of those cases, you will be greeted with the following dialog, where you can select all the Maven projects you just downloaded and import them.

[image]

Comment: It worked like a charm, but imported 66 projects to my workspace... I should have expected it, right?

Comment: @LuigiCortese Well, it has imported all the Maven modules of this project. So... yes :)

Comment: This is why it took almost half an hour on my old Toshiba... =) I've found [this](https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway/wiki/Importing-source-code-into-Eclipse) resource in the meanwhile, if you want to add it to your answer it may be helpful to someone else. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since your project seems to be using pom.xml, use [Maven's eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) to create an Eclipse project.