# Using Eclipse for a Maven project with multiple .pom files from a GitHub project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, github

My problem is quite simple, but I am relatively new to Java and very much new to Maven projects and GitHub.

I want to download [this](https://github.com/joelpob/jbetfairng) project and try to do my own modifications to it. The problem is that it is dependent on a bunch of packages that are referred to in the .pom files. I'm convinced that they all can be easily downloaded using the pom files, but I can't figure out how to do it though.

Any help out there is much appreciated! Thank you. I use Eclipse Mars and I know how to convert a project to a Maven project.

EDIT: I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33465233/how-to-import-a-github-hosted-project-as-a-java-project-in-eclipse) solution, but after I've imported the project from Git it isn't recognized as a Maven project when using "File > Import... > Existing Maven Projects". Note that there are no pom.xml in the project - only .pom files.

Comment: Maybe this could help:
[Maven Package](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't explain what to do with when there is no pom.xml and multiple .pom files...

Comment: Have you tried renaming the *.pom file to pom.xml?