# How to build pom.xml in a maven project which is downloaded from github?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am so so new in maven that's way I need help for this problem. Firstly I downloaded [this](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java) folder from the github. I want to use these libs in that folder. I created a clear new maven project on eclipce but that's all. There is a pom.xml inside it too. I do not know what I have to do with these both folder and new maven project. How can I use these libs on my project ?

Comment: 1. Make sure you have maven binary and add them in your PATH variable; 2. in the project folder where you could see `pom.xml`, type `mvn compile` in command line; 3. Wait until the compilation.

Comment: I realy do not know where I am going to to do. I have only that folder eclipce what will I do with these things ?

Comment: you can either compile it using command line or just import this project into Eclipse

Comment: Take a look at this answer of mine also http://stackoverflow.com/a/33465309/1743880. Screenshots all the way :).

Comment: Best is to configure Maven so it can consume the repositories given in the documentation....

Comment: Thanks everyone the problem solved by your helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Maven project downloaded and unpacked on your file system, and you have a Eclipse with maven support, you should not create a new maven project but instead open the import dialogue from

```
File -> Import...
```

[image: File->import]

and choose

```
Maven -> Existing Maven projects
```

[image: Maven->Existing Maven projects]

and click next.  Then click "Browse" and navigate to the folder where pom.xml file for the project you checked out is.  After clicking Ok, the projects will be imported and made available in Eclipse.

[image: Browse]