# How to preinstall Eclipse m2e configurators (Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

When importing maven projects into Eclipse IDE fresh install, 
there is a pop-up question to "Setup Maven plugin connections"

If not to install there will be errors shown in pom.xml like

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.20.0:validate-id (execution: default-validate-id, phase: validate)

**How to install m2e configurators at any time** (e.g. before when preparing Eclipse package for team, or again after interactive installation failed over network)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can install M2Eclipse connectors at any time by going to "Window > Preferences > Maven > Discovery".

[image]

Then when you click "Open Catalog", you will be greeted with a pop-up that will display all available M2E connectors to install. You need to select the one you want, click "Finish" and follow the standard installation process.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Install m2e from command line:

```
/opt/eclipse/eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -noSplash -repository http://beust.com/eclipse  -installIUs org.testng.eclipse.feature.group
/opt/eclipse/eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -noSplash -repository http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse  -installIUs edu.umd.cs.findbugs.plugin.eclipse.feature.group
/opt/eclipse/eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -noSplash -repository http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/update  -installIUs net.sf.eclipsecs.feature.group
/opt/eclipse/eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -noSplash -repository http://coderplus.com/m2e-update-sites/maven-remote-resources-plugin -installIUs com.coderplus.m2e.remoteresourcesfeature.feature.group
/opt/eclipse/eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -noSplash -repository http://ianbrandt.github.io/m2e-maven-dependency-plugin/ -installIUs com.ianbrandt.tools.m2e.mdp.feature.feature.group
/opt/eclipse/eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -noSplash -repository http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2e-extensions/m2e-jdt-compiler/ -installIUs org.jboss.tools.m2e.jdt.feature.feature.group
```

Comment: Nodeclipse Installer https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodeclipse#nodeclipse-cli-installer would give nicer suntax like `nodeclipse install org.jboss.tools.m2e.jdt.feature.feature.group from http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2e-extensions/m2e-jdt-compiler/` But there problem with this answer it is still unknown where to get full list. +1 anyway for hint of command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch the Maven connector discovery wizard again by finding one of the missing connector errors in the Markers view, right clicking on it, and selecting `Quick fix` or `ctrl + 1` while it's selected.

[image: Markers view]

The quick fix will allow you to launch the wizard to discover connectors for all the Maven errors.