# Installing m2e connectors manually

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I'm using *Eclipse Mars*, and I have a Maven application using `build-helper-maven-plugin`, that is not covered by `m2e` by default, so I need to add a connector. The point is, I can add the connector when importing the maven project:

[image]

However, I have no idea how I would do this manually, when the project is already in the workspace. The pom have an error, `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.10:add-source`, but I can't find the option `install m2e connector` or something like that.

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824645/how-to-preinstall-eclipse-m2e-configurators-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lif

Comment: Well, I would prefer that it finds the "best suitable connector", but that works.

Answer (score 6):

The P2 Update site is here:

```
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-buildhelper/0.15.0/N/0.15.0.201207090124/
```

---

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36824717/91497) helped me to discover how Eclipse knows it.

There is a Catalog that can be opened from the preferences:

[image: Eclipse Preferences]

You can follow the link manually: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/discovery/directory-1.8.xml

If you download the `org.eclipse.m2e.discovery.oss-catalog-1.6.jar` referenced as entry and you unzip it, the you will find a `plugin.xml` file:

```
org.eclipse.m2e.discovery.oss-catalog-1.6
├── META-INF
│   └── MANIFEST.MF
├── images
│   ├── extras-48.png
│   └── scm-32.png
├── lifecycle
│   ├── com.coderplus.m2e.jaxws.feature.group.pluginxml
│   ├── com.coderplus.m2e.jaxws.feature.group.xml
│   ├── ..
│   ├── org.eclipse.m2e.discovery.lifecycles.tycho.pluginxml
│   ├── org.eclipse.m2e.discovery.lifecycles.tycho.xml
│   ├── org.maven.ide.eclipse.ajdt.pluginxml
│   └── org.maven.ide.eclipse.ajdt.xml
└── plugin.xml
```

And this file contains the information with the P2 Update site:

```
<connectorDescriptor siteUrl="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-buildhelper/0.15.0/N/0.15.0.201207090124/" id="org.eclipse.m2e.discovery.lifecyclemapping.buildhelper" groupId="lifecycles" description="buildhelper" categoryId="org.eclipse.m2e.discovery.category.lifecycles" name="buildhelper" provider="Takari, Inc." license="EPL" kind="lifecycles">
  <iu id="org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper.feature.feature.group" />
  <overview summary="buildhelper" />
</connectorDescriptor>
```

Comment: This is a very good answer (and shoule be accepted).